# How i fill combobox items in Radgridview manually using in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, radgridview

How I fill combobox items in Radgridview manually without using datasource in vb.net I have a Radgridview in my form.(radgridview1) radgridview1 contained 3 Column and column number 3 is combobox type. I want to fill each combobox in column 3 with this data using code: UNP IPE Angle BOX Other Profile. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: here what you meant by manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GridTemplateColumn` like the following.

```
       <telerik:GridTemplateColumn ItemStyle-Wrap="true" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle"
                        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center" AllowFiltering="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                        HeaderStyle-Width="3%" ItemStyle-Width="3%" HeaderText="Profile">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadComboBox>
                                <Items>
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="UNP" Value="UNP" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="IPE" Value="IPE" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="ANGLE" Value="ANGLE" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="BOX" Value="BOX" />
                                    <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Other Profile" Value="OTHER" />
                                </Items>
                            </telerik:RadComboBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
       </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

or else you can bind each `comboBox` in `_ItemDataBound`

Comment: thanks a lot but i think this is asp.net code but i want winform  app code.